# div r/|r| = 2/|r|

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to proof:

$\nabla \cdot  \dfrac {\vec r} {\vec {|r|}} =\dfrac {2}{\vec {|r|}}$

I know that $\nabla \cdot (f \vec A) = f(\nabla \cdot \vec A) +\vec A \cdot (\nabla f)$ where f is a scalar and A a vector valued function.

But I still can't simplify the equation...in fact I don't even come close to it.

Comment: For starters: Are you working in $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^3$? Next, can you compute the gradient of $|\vec r|$? This can be done geometrically or directly by the formulas. Then it's just a matter of using the power rule to differentiate $1/|\vec r|$. At any rate, welcome to MSE, but please do show us what work you've been able to do, so we can help more effectively.

Comment: Thanks! I'm working in R^3. And $grad |\vec r|$ as well as $ grad |\vec r|^{-1}$ 
 are solvable for me..which is why after an hour of trying I decided to post it here.

Comment: Are solvable or are not? Just compute $\text{grad}|\vec r|$ in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: are solvable! Now my original question is, too. Your answer made me think I had to have a pretty dumb error..which was true. In a task before this one, r was defined as the euclidean norm...so that I used $\vec r ={r_1,r_2,r_3}$ BUT $|r|=(x^2+...)^{1/2}$, (different variables) which of course led me nowhere.....

Comment: Oh, well, that was wrong .... to have different letters :) Glad you’ve sorted it all out now!

Comment: Don't try to find a logic there...I was just confused. Thanks! Without your questioning  I wouldn't have found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the vector identity you need.

So : 
$$\nabla \cdot (\vec{r}/|\vec{r}|)=\frac{1}{|\vec{r}|}\nabla \cdot \vec{r}+\vec{r} \cdot \nabla(1/|\vec{r}|)$$

Now $\nabla \cdot \vec{r}=3. $ Easiest to prove in cartesian coordinates.

If you express $1/|\vec{r}|$ as a function and cartesian coordinates then differentiate with respect to x, you find the $i_{th}$ component of your gradient. By symmetry the pattern persists with the other dimensions establishing that $\nabla(1/|\vec{r}|)=-\vec{r}/|\vec{r}|^3$

Now put it all together:

$$\nabla \cdot (\vec{r}/|\vec{r}|)=\frac{3}{|\vec{r}|}+\frac{\vec{r}\cdot (-\vec{r})}{|\vec{r}|^3}=\frac{2}{|\vec{r}|}$$